# $\sqrt {3} $ is irrational (proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

$\sqrt {3} \in Q$. Then, $\sqrt{3} = \frac ab$ with the lowest term for $a,b \in Z$.

Then, $3b^2=a^2$, which implies that $a^2$ is divisible by 3.

That is, $a$ is also divisible by 3 (by fundamental theorem of arithmetic).

I don't understand here $a^2$ divisible by 3 implies $a$ divisible by 3.

Could you explain it?

Comment: [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).

Comment: Can $a^2$ be a multiple of three without $a$ being a multiple of three? Consider that $$(3n\pm 1)^2 = 3(3n^2\pm 2n)\color{red}{+1}.$$

Comment: The linked question has 2 instead of 3, but the proof is virtually identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with integers, recall that $cd$ divisible by a prime $k$ implies $c$ is divisible by $k$ or $d$ is divisible by $k$. $a^2$ divisible by 3 implies $a \cdot a$ divisible by 3. So, $a$ is divisible by $3$ or $a$ is divisible by $3$ (This statement occurs by taking the left $a$ and the right $a$; if you don't understand this, in the example mentioned let $c = a$ and $d=a$).

Comment: `cd divisible by k implies c is divisible by k or d is divisible by k` Only if $k$ is a prime.Otherwise take $c=d, k=c^2$ for example.

Comment: It's simple. Thanks.

Comment: @SihyunKim Be careful! This answer is wrong.

Comment: why is it wrong??

Comment: What am I missing here? Last time I checked, 3 was still prime.

Comment: @MJD The original version of the answer said that $k | cd \implies k | c$ or $k | d$ unconditionally; it made no use of the fact that $3$ is prime.

Comment: But since the theorem was applicable in this instance, the answer was correct. Even if the answer omitted to mention one of the conditions, the condition was still satisfied. In my opinion your claim that "this answer is wrong" was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the prime factorization of $a$.

Suppose on the contrary that $3$ is not a factor of $a$. Then squaring $a$ will also not make  $3$ appears in the prime factorization of $a^2$. Hence $3$ will not be a factor of $a^2$.